# Null-coalescing operator inside ternary

Tags: c#, ternary-operator, null-coalescing-operator

I have this C# code:

```
data[j].Actual[0] = data[j].Actual.Count != 0 ? (data[j].Actual[0] ?? 0) : 0;
```

What I want to do is to check if the count is 0, in this case the value of the variable should be set on 0.

In case the count is different of 0, I want to check with null-coalescing operator if that value is there, otherwise return 0.

The problem I have is that I get this error message:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection. Parameter name: index

My guess is that even when `data[j].Actual.Count` is 0 it doesn't the result to 0 but it tries to do something with the null-coalescing operator.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `Any suggestions?` don't try to be fancy and just write readable code

Comment: what are the types here? what is `data[j].Actual`?

Comment: your problem, though, is `data[j].Actual[0] ?? 0` is still trying to access an item at index 0.  If that collection has no items, the null-coalesce won't save the exception.  You'd have to check that it has at least one item.

Comment: @MarcGravell a list of `double?`

Comment: @Jonesopolis that part will never be accessed if the `Count` is `0`; the problem is on the left hand side

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is the assignment; if `data[j].Actual` is an empty (list/array/whatever), then you can't just *assign* `data[j].Actual[0]` to anything. If this is an *array*, you can't do *anything* (except maybe create a new array). If this is a *list*, you would need to `.Add` a value.

I would simplify the code:

```
var actual = data[j].Actual;
if (actual.Count == 0)
{
    actual.Add(0);
    // or if this is an array: data[j].Actual = new double?[] {0}; 
}
else if (actual[0] == null)
{
    actual[0] = 0;
}
```

This isn't one line, but it is easy to understand.

Answer (score 3):

look carefully

```
data[j].Actual[0] = data[j].Actual.Count != 0 ? (data[j].Actual[0] ?? 0) : 0;
```

You are assigning to `Actual[0]`. if `Actual.Count` is 0 you get out of range exception. you cant use ternary. use if statement.

```
if(data[j].Actual.Count != 0)
{
   data[j].Actual[0] = data[j].Actual[0] ?? 0;
}
// else you don't need to set anything because there is nothing to set!
```